# power supply remote sense protection resistor value?

Tags: power-supply, resistors, remote-sense

There is often a 100 ohm resistor between the +sense and +ve and between the -sense and -ve outputs of bench power supplies. This protects the output from high voltage if the sense wires are accidentally disconnected. So why are these resistors low value like 100 ohms? What if it's 1K?

I'm making a 6V power supply and can't seem to see much difference in the output whether it is 100 ohms or 1k. The output voltage always falls if the sense wire gets disconnected, whether the resistor is 100 ohms or 1K.

Also, it seems 1K is better, if the actual power line gets disconnected. The 1k will survive, while the 100 ohms will burn up, possibly taking the sense wires with it.

So, what am I missing?

**edit**:

I think the question was not clear. There are no feedback resistors involved here. These are the resistors I am talking about: Rs and Rs shown below. They will burn up if they are low value and the output cable is disconnected (they are usually 100 ohm 0.5 watt; sometimes even [5 ohm](http://powerblog.vicorpower.com/2014/04/using-remote-sensing-to-ensure-accurate-point-of-load-voltage-control/) or [10 ohm](https://www.us.tdk-lambda.com/media/292128/tdk-lambda-blog-040213.pdf)). But they will not burn up if they are 1K 0.25W. Image from [here](https://www.sunpower-uk.com/glossary/what-is-remote-sensing/) and [here](http://power-topics.blogspot.in/2013/04/power-supply-remote-sense-mistakes-and.html).

[image]

I cannot seriously think the resistor is low value to decrease noise. There must be dozens of much higher value resistors in the power supply itself. And this is not a feedback resistor, it is a protection resistor (protecting against inadvertent high voltage at the output if the sense wires are accidentally disconnected). Almost no current should be flowing through them during normal operation.

PS: my power supply has only the +ve sense wire, so will have only the one resistor. Ground return is directly connected, no sense wire or protection resistor.

**update**: to make it more clear, this is the output stage that I currently have (after putting in the back to back diodes). The power supply is rated 6V 1A, but with sensing failure may go upto 9V 1A. The 40m ohm resistance comes from a dual mosfet protection system. The 1N5408 is to protect against accidental high input voltages from output (and prevent the crowbar from nuisance tripping). It can be bypassed. The 20m ohm is output cable resistance. Please ignore the 10k resistor, it is temporary. Local sensing can be done before the mosfet switch or at the load (indicated by the unconnected bent wires going from the op amp). Circuit works fine with all resistor values. If I were to put in parasitic capacitance to simulate, where should it be?

[image]

Comment: The higher the value, the [noisier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnson%E2%80%93Nyquist_noise) the result.

Comment: Power supply is usually supplying DC

Comment: The resistors don't care.

Comment: Sounds like your wired your entire connection wrong if the feedback resistor burns up. Draw a diagram to understand what are you doing.

Comment: I have edited the question to make it more clear. Please remove the vote to close the question. This is a valid question and the comments are not really relevant to the issue here.

Comment: Given the schematic you show, how much current is likely to be passing through the resistors?

Comment: In normal use, probably in nano amperes. But if the output cable is accidentally disconnected, then for a 30V supply, with a 100 ohm resistor, it may be up to 0.3A, or 9W. Clearly too much for a 0.5W resistor. and this is a well known problem. With a 1K resistor this becomes 30mA and 0.9W, easily solved. Increasing the resistor value does not change the sensing ability, as input is into high impedance op amp. So why is the resistor value limited to 5 or 10 or 100 ohms?

Comment: Then you haven't looked closely enough. There is an error amp in between the resistors.

Comment: I agree, high value unbalanced resistors here would change the gain from unity to something else (and add noise) for a differential amplifier. But not so if it is an instrumentation amplifier perhaps? I don't have a differential amplifier there, due to only one sense wire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error amp generally has an input impedance in the few k region, as it is often really an opamp with feedback, so you want the sense resistors to be small (But large enough to be swamped by the cable conductance) to minimise error.

Secondly, an unconnected set of sense leads look like a capacitor, so you want the sense resistors small so that the resulting pole is way above the loop frequency to avoid impacting the loop stability.

Thirdly resistors add voltage noise, more for higher values, it's a physics thing.

One canny approach is to parallel the resistors with a pair of back to back diodes of sufficient robustness to handle the output current, means that you get at most a 1.4V error.

Comment: Thanks. Does this mean that if my error amp is not a differential amplifier, but just an op amp with no feedback from the output pin (because I just have one sense wire on the +ve line, no ground sensing), the value of the resistor will not matter as it is not influencing any op amp feedback resistors? Also, with one sense wire there will not be any capacitance between it and ground. Thanks for the diode tip, that is working perfectly.

Comment: Of course there will be capacitance, there is always capacitance, in this case, likely to the common return wire. I would suggest that almost any opamp likely has sufficient GBP that you would need at least some capacitance in feedback to get the thing to be stable. There is a reason almost everyone uses resistors of less then 1k here.

Comment: I updated with the output section of my supply. I'm using slow op amps (LM358), can oscillation still be an issue?

Comment: Of course oscillation can still be an issue, even the LM358 has a GBP of ~1MHz, and what power device are you using as the pass transistor? Do a small signal Bode plot (Easy here you can just place a signal generator between the output and the sense pin and plot the output gain and phase).

Comment: I'm using a TIP122. I've never done a bode plot before, will have to look it up. There is also a differential amp for high side current sensing, not shown in my partial schematic above. So far everything is simulating without any oscillations (not even with the 1mF output cap visible above).

Comment: Sigh, spice in the hands of beginners, never a good look. The problem with sims is that they are only as good as the things you bother to model, and beginners never know what parasitics to model. Also, all spice models are simplifications, they sort of have to be to get the maths to converge. Get some bits, and BUILD the thing, then compare what the real thing does with the simulation, then tweak the sim to match (more or less) reality, it is time well spent and will teach you much about the care and feeding of spice simulations. Eventually you will learn where the traps are.

Comment: yeah, I guess it's "a trap for young players" like me! One thing I've found out, if it doesn't simulate right, it hardly ever works right on the breadboard, or pcb. I guess this one will be a learning experience, and I'll leave space on the PCB for corrections.

Comment: Spice is quite good at saying "not going to work", you can usually rely on that, but you need to be far more cautious when the spice model says "This works", that is often not something you can rely on.

Answer (score 1):

Well, like you said, these resistors are clearly there for the sense lines to follow the output voltage. The only reason I can think of that they are low value is because with low value the sense line „react“ faster. Think of some small capacitance between the sense lines. If the output changes, then this capacitance is charged faster with low Rs.